# Open source code within organization

Tags: github, open-source

i want to open source my code within the organization,but not to ppl outside the organization.

plz advise how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at [this link](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a private repository, like bit-bucket. It's free.

Alternatively you can set up a git server within your organization (which can be done from any server), but is more responsibility and more work.